# CNN accuracy increasing too fast - Keras

Tags: python, keras, classification, image-recognition

I'm studying more about Convolutional Neural Networks, so I tried to create a simple image classifier, which should classify an image either a cat or a dog. The problem comes when I train the model, in the first seconds it already is in about 94% of accuracy. I guess that for some reason it's overfitting.
The dataset can be found here: [Dataset](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0UJkGatK_DuOFo2WjlOMFQ5V1U?usp=sharing)

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from scipy import misc
import numpy as np

def build_classifier():
    #Model based on 'https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Le_Lu/publication/277335071/figure/fig8/AS:294249976352779@1447166069905/Figure-8-The-proposed-CNN-model-architecture-is-composed-of-five-convolutional-layers.png'
    #It's smarter to add layer without creating variables because of the processing, but as a small dataset it doesn't matter a lot.
    classifier = Sequential()

    conv1 = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(2,2), activation='relu', input_shape=(64,64,3))
    conv2 = Conv2D(filters=192, kernel_size=(2,2), activation='relu')
    conv3 = Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(2,2), activation='relu')
    conv4 = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(2,2), activation='relu')
    conv5 = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(2,2), activation='relu')
    pooling1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))
    pooling2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))
    pooling3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))
    fcl1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')
    fcl2 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')
    fcl3 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    dropout1= Dropout(0.5)
    dropout2 = Dropout(0.5)
    flatten = Flatten()

    layers = [conv1, pooling1, conv2, pooling2, conv3, conv4, conv5,
             pooling3, flatten, fcl1, dropout1, fcl2, dropout2, fcl3]

    for l in layers:
        classifier.add(l)

    return classifier

model = build_classifier()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/train',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='banery')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/test',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800)`
```

Comment: Why not use a softmax layer for the output? Furthermore, are you shuffling your data?

Comment: actually I didn't shuffled, thanks for that, but why should I do it? (Considering that my train and test images do not coincide)

Comment: Check this: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/data-shuffling-why-important-machine-learning-how-do-deepak-n-gowda The basic idea is that the classifier should not become biased to patterns in the training data, which might influence prediction and lower the quality of prediction.

Comment: All right, thank you, it really was because of the data, my dataset had similar images on both training and test sets.

Comment: Is it working as expected now? I think it should.

Comment: Yes, it still training since your answer and now is about 83%, I think that it's going well.

Comment: Your flatten layer should come before the fully connected dense layer, Are you sure this is still working correctly?

Comment: And it is, the sequence is on the 'layers' array

Comment: I see, havent seen the sequential model setup like that. Is this now working?

Comment: It is, but when I use the predict method I get [[0., 1.]]. But I don't know if it's a dog or a cat. Any clue?